# Regex Match extraction

Tags: c#, regex

I've got some text that follows the format

```
text ( text + numbers | text + numbers | 2-4 digit number text)
```

I'm interested in extracting the 2-4 digit number from this string in C#.  My regEx string is

```
.*?\|.*?\|([0-9][0-9][0-9]?[0-9]?)
```

This correctly returns whether the string matches or not, but I'm not able to extract just the digits.

I've tried calling regex.match(input).Value, but it returns the entire input.

I must be missing something - any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Won't ([0-9]{2,4}) work for your regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex defines a `Group`- inside parenthesis with the value you want. Using just `Value` from the Match object returns the entire string that was matched for the regex.

Use regex.Match(input).Groups[1].Value for extracting the number.